# Going from one View controller to another in swift

Tags: swift, animation, viewcontroller

I need to go from one view controller to another without performing any action like clicking on button so that I can put some animation in first view controller and then get to the second one.

Comment: A simple google search can lead you to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform any animation in the first view controller's `viewDidAppear()` method  using the using the `UIView.animate()` and load the second controller in the completion block as follows:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: 
{
    //add animation code here
}) { (isAnimationComplete) in
    //load new controller here
    let controller = SecondViewController()
    navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1: go to storyboard and create a manual segue between first and second view controller (control-click and drag from yellow circle above FirstViewController to the body of SecondViewController)

2: click on the segue in the background and go to attributes inspector (4th button in top right panel) and in the "Identifier" text field, put "SegueName" (or whatever you want)

3: go to the .swift file for FirstViewController and add the performSegue function.

```
class FirstViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueName", sender: self)
}

}
```

Putting the performSegue inside of the viewDidLoad() would cause your app to segue as soon as the screen is loaded.  If you need help coding the segue to happen after your animations (or whatever code is set to run on FirstViewController), I would need to see the files for both view controllers.

Answer (score -1):

Try these steps of **simple navigation just change the flag of animated true**

If you want to learn Controller transitions animation you can go for these tutorials.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/359-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions

Step 1 - Create button on ViewController and create IBAction of the button on viewController.

Step 2 - Create the function which navigates to secondViewController.

```
@IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton) {

        navigateToSecondViewController()

    }

    func navigateToSecondViewController() {

        let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Step 3 - If you are using navigatationController then you can push the controller.

```
func navigateToSecondViewController() {

        let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: He want it without any action and you have added a button with action.

Comment: He mentioned there performing any action like a button and I create function of navigating to the second controller so you can call anywhere and you have to just call function nothing else.

Comment: This answer is working fine, and I give the tutorial link for transition animation